# It was creative to combine these two materials for a painting. - general past thing or single past event?

Tags: meaning, clauses, to-infinitive

"It was creative to combine these two materials for a painting."

Does this sentence have two interpretations?

(1)

> Interpreted as a comment about a general thing. "Generally speaking, combining these two materials for a painting was creative."

(2)

> Interpreted as a comment about a single past event. "Somebody combined these two materials for a painting. I am saying that was creative."

I think even when a subject is included, it still has two meanings.

"It was creative for my sister to combine these two materials for a painting."

(3)

> Interpreted as a comment about a general thing. "Generally speaking, combining these two materials for a painting was creative for my sister."

(4)

> Interpreted as a comment about a single past event. "my sister combined these two materials for a painting. I am saying that single past event was creative."

---

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: For me your general-thing interpretations don’t work. In all these examples of  “It was creative” that do work, the antecedent of *it* is a one-time event or circumstance.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Without context, I would understand it to be a comment on a particular painting.

Comment: The preposition should be *It was creative **OF** my sister [to do something].*

Comment: I think it's misleading for learners to think *"This construction has two possible meanings"*. The reality is words don't have *any* "meaning" without context, so we should only be concerned with what the text means *in some specific context* (in the real world, text is almost *always* "contextualised", and it's a fool's errand to seek to identify some "default context" that's not actually present).

Answer (score 2):

I think the core of the question here is about the tense of the verb. Let's throw out paintings and creativity and take a simpler sentence. How about "It was smart to read the owner's manual." If you mean to say simply that it's always a good idea, in general, to read owner's manuals, then using *was* like this doesn't make sense. It seems to refer to a specific event, especially with no context provided. Notice, it can *also* be true generally, but the sentence seems to be talking about a specific instance even if it's a general truth.

That doesn't mean that past tense is always specific. It can be general if you've already created a context in which you're talking generally about a broad past setting, like "In the Middle Ages it was useful to own a horse."

Meaning always comes from context.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decide from the grammar, but from the meaning of "creative".

If something is "creative" then it must show some originality. Simply "combining two materials" cannot always be creative.  Always doing something the same way is the opposite of creativity. On the other hand,  if this refers to a specific event then the meaning is clear and sound. So only one meaning is consistent and that must be the intended meaning.